# Yii, ActiveRecord

Tags: php, yii

```
$data = Test::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $id));
```

Как я понял все атрибуты хранятся в массиве `$data->_attrib`, но проблема в том, что он private и я не могу к не могу обращаться. Есть ли возможность вытащить все значения массива `_attrib`, а еще лучше получить ассоциативный массив вида `mas[attrib] = value;`?

Comment: `( new Test() )->attributes`. [Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#$attributes-detail).

Comment: Получилось! Не подскажите, как теперь, это привести в ассоциативный массив:  [params] => a:15:{s:2:"id";N;s:10:"request_id";s:5:"90748";s:7:"version";N;s:4:"name";s:0:"";s:6:"series";s:1:"2";s:5:"modes";a:1:{i:0;s:16:"Основной";}.  Я думал это JSON, но оказалось нет.

Comment: Ну так что это за формат? Вы же пишите код, а не кто-то другой — значит вы знаете что это за формат раз хотите его использовать ...

Answer (score 1):

В Документации
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getAttributes-detail

Пример
if ($data) {
   $data->getAttributes(['name'])
}